# how to extract the corresponding Label text & CheckBox value into the button Click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

Now I want to extract the corresponding Label text and checkBox values to the button i.e, I have created the labels & CheckBoxes in the DDL SelectIndexChanged now I want to store them in a Button click... How can I extract them into Button Click event??????

I have created them based on the DDL selection.....

```
<div class="row-fluid" runat="server" id="Labeldiv"> 

</div>
```

.

```
protected void EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            Label NewLabel = new Label();
            NewLabel.ID = "Label" + i;
            CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
            newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);
        } 
}
protected void Done_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  con.Open();
  int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string labelId = "Label" + i.ToString();
        Label NewLabel = (Label)this.Labeldiv.FindControl(labelId);
        string checkBoxId = "Checkbox" + i.ToString();
        CheckBox newcheck = (CheckBox)this.Labeldiv.FindControl(checkBoxId);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into EventDays(EventDay,EventStatus)values(@EventDay,@EventStatus)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDay", NewLabel.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventStatus", newcheck.Checked ? "true" : "false");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you binding the data to the drop down list and the label text during the Page.Init event?  If so, the Viewstate will be used to select the correct item

Comment: @Pooli, see my code... I have updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must put that code in Page_Load()..

TO do that, see following code....

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (!IsPostBack)
            StartDate_TB.Text = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
        EventDuration();

}
private void EventDuration()
{
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(StartDate_TB.Text);
        int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Label NewLabel = new Label();
            NewLabel.ID = "Label" + i;
            var eventDate = dt.AddDays(i);
            NewLabel.Text = eventDate.ToLongDateString();

            CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
            newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='row-fluid'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class='h1size'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</span>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch pull-right' data-on='info'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FindControl to find a control based on its id. The following sample assumes that you want to get all the labels and checkboxes that are valid based on the selection of the ComboBox:

```
int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    string labelId = "Label" + i.ToString();
    Label NewLabel = (Label) this.LabelDiv.FindControl(labelId);
    string checkBoxId = "Checkbox" + i.ToString();
    CheckBox newcheck = (Checkbox)this.LabelDiv.FindControl(checkBoxId);
}
```

However, you should recreate the controls in OnInit of the page. See the this article on [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317794/en-us) for details.

As already stated in one of your last questions, it might also be a viable option to create the controls statically and use the Visible property to show or hide controls or to use a repeater with a matching item template. 
This would be much easier than to deal with dynamic control creation and its side effects and should IMHO be possible as the maximum number of controls is defined in the combobox.

Comment: pls see my code in question, I have edited... and How can I recreate the controls in OnInit()??

Comment: It shows error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' at the line 'cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventDay", NewLabel.Text);'

Comment: @Thor The error most likely means that NewLabel is null. Might be that it couldn't find the label with that id. Can you step through with the debugger and check whether the code works for some runs or does it fail one the first run?

Comment: @THOR: which error? My answer was related to the NullReferenceException you mentioned ("Object reference not set to an instance of an object").

Comment: At the 1st repetetion the error occurs and while that time it shows null at NewLabel, newCheck.....

Comment: @Thor Are the label ids exactly the same when you create them and when you use FindControl? What is the value of the CheckBoxes, also null?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42238/discussion-between-markus-and-thor)